# Fire event on Eloquent User Model password property update

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a User model with a password property.

If I retrieve it from the Database using:

```
$user = User::find(3);
```

And change the password value(in Controller):

```
$user->password = Input::get('passwordValue')
```

I want to trigger the **Eloquent updating event** that will first create a salt and concatenate the $salt with $passwordValue before assigning the value to $user->password something like:

```
$user->password = md5($salt . $passwordValue)
```

After this I can save the $user:

```
$user->save();
```

I want this event to fire every time the user changes his password in his profile page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a setter for the password field in your model:

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
{
    $salt = 'whatever';
    $this->attributes['password'] = md5($salt.$value);
}
```

Then, in your controller (or whatever) code, just set the password using the plaintext version:

```
$user->password = Input::get('new_password');
```

---

However, it should be noted that, in Laravel, you really shouldn't be setting the password by using md5 with a salt, but instead use the hashing functions that Laravel provides:

```
$this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($value);
```

That'll create a much stronger, bcrypt-generated password. You do, however, have to change the way you check the password, though it's pretty simple:

```
if (Hash::check($plaintext_password, $user->password)) {
    // password is correct
}
```

However, further to this, you should use the Auth functions to handle logins so you don't even need to use `Hash::check()` directly:

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('username' => Input::get('username'), 'password' => Input::get('password'))) {
    // logged in, redirect
} else {
    // attempt failed, set message and redirect
}
```

Comment: Simple and exactly what I need. Tnx :)